# Multiples menus pointing to the same article

Tags: joomla, organization, joomla3.2

I'm building a website using Joomla. This site has lots of menus, but some of the menus are just duplicates of the others. So, there are multiple menu items pointing to the same article (with the same permisions, styles, etc). For example: I have an "About" article, and a link from the main menu, a couple from two different side menus and another from a button menu. And, of course, every link has a different url (/about, /about-side1, /about-side2, /btn-about).

Is this correct? Am I building the website correctly, or should I organize the menus in another way? Is it possible to have all the links with the same url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid having many different URLs for the same page. If you are pointing to the exact same page, instead of creating a new menu item when you make the new link us the type "Alias."  The alias type will give you the choice of all other menu items that exist.  The sef url create will be the same as that in the original item.